# Why do we have romatic feelings?

Tags: personality, behavior, sexuality

People who are asexual feel little to no sexual attraction towards others, but they can have romantic relationships. From how sexual and romantic feelings are different, it has made me start to wonder about the psychology about it. While we all know sexual attraction was created so species can procreate, why do we have romantic feelings, and where did it originate from?

Comment: While I try to work out how best to answer your question, what have you found reading or using internet search engines? Goggle has come up with plenty of helpful links such as https://lgbtq.unc.edu/resources/exploring-identities/asexuality-attraction-and-romantic-orientation/ which may help in the meantime

Comment: Apparently romantic feelings relate to higher order consciousness which only certain mammals and surprisingly some birds possess (some birds also developed highly advanced languages), compared to the more primordial type consciousness such as sex attraction manifested from almost all kinds of animals. Thus birds might have romantic feelings and wants too which could also be reflected via their unique singing capabilities which, say, reptiles lack.

Comment: Parents' role does not end at copulation.